# How to get Django to send requests every 5 minutes

Tags: python, django, django-views

New to Djano but have used it to construct fairly straightforward web applications (adding views and urls is like 90% of my workflow). I need to be able to send out a set of requests every 5 minutes or so and then update my database based on the results of the requests (all HTTP). I'm not sure how this functionality would be created (send requests at regular time intervals) or stored in the application (e.g. which files).

Comment: Check out [this tutorial.](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2014/05/18/setting-up-an-asynchronous-task-queue-for-django-using-celery-redis/)

Comment: @Dan bit more heavy duty then I was hoping for. Thanks though I'll read more about it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same tasks in my applications.
Using something like ZeroMQ, Celery or RabbitMQ is rather sophisticated and excess for such a task. Django allows you to install `CRON` in your `virtualenv`. Look at the [django-crontab](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab).